# Kerning Approach for Letters with Large Spaces

Tags: kerning

Is there a specific approach to kerning letters with large spaces (apologies if there's a technical term for this)?

For example, the 'T' and 'Y' below both have large amounts of space either side of the 'stem' in the center (in comparison to, say, 'N' which has straight sides). If adjusting the position of the bullets, where would be best the best place to start?

[image: Example of letter spacing]

I appreciate kerning isn't necessarily an exact science, but any tips on what to focus on would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

[image: example]

I would say it's design dependant, but I think a good place to start would be with creating a visually equal spacing where my green arrows are while trying to keep in mind the pink arrow.

The spacing does not have to match 100% (my green arrows are identical widths), but just tweak until it appears balanced. Like you said, it's not an exact science, but you'll know when you are close.